# Must non-Burmese citizens staying at hotels in Myanmar register with local authorities? If so, how?

Tags: legal, hotels, myanmar, registration

I read on https://qz.com/113211/myanmars-hotels-are-full-but-its-banning-homestays-because-of-unmannered-foreigners/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171113060608/https://qz.com/113211/myanmars-hotels-are-full-but-its-banning-homestays-because-of-unmannered-foreigners/)):

> By law, people staying at hotels must register with local authorities.

However, the page doesn't give any reference and dates back from August 8, 2013.

Must non-Burmese citizens staying at hotels in Myanmar register with local authorities? If so, how?

Comment: The hotel registers you.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thank you you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer

Comment: 4 word answers are generally not well regarded, and there's not much more to say on the matter. :)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas life is short, no need to write a book if 4 words are sufficient :)